# Unity - how to fast forward to a percentage of animation?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, percentage, lerp

Ok, I have looked up everything to do with Unity's Animator, and I know you can jump to specific frames and get percentage of animation with https://answers.unity.com/questions/1418940/how-can-i-know-a-percent-of-animation.html and https://answers.unity.com/questions/181903/jump-to-a-specific-frame-in-an-animation.html

I haven't seen anything on this, however - like in the game Causality (made with Unity) I need to do something like Magic leap does with its website on scroll: https://www.magicleap.com

I have an animation I am creating on my model in Blender, and rather than running it, I need to fast forward/go to certain percentage of the animation based on its y axis position.

Right now I can drag my model up/down on y axis, and I have a max and min `transform.position.y` that the model can move on (like a dolley)

```
Vector3 goTo = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, (initObjPos.y+touchDiff), transform.position.z);
                if (goTo.y >= maxHeight) { //max = 0.251f in y, and min?
                    transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, maxHeight, transform.position.z);
                } else if (goTo.y <= minHeight) {
                    transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, minHeight, transform.position.z);
                } else { //lower
                    transform.position = goTo;
                }
```

Here's a visualization of how I need the animation to be finished at 100% when y position is at max, and 0% at min height, and be able to move back and forth as user drags:

[image]

Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you know the number of total frames? If so I think it is solved.

Comment: Yes I do - each model may have different number but how would you do this with 100 frames say?

Comment: Are you using a single animation for this?

Comment: Basically, since you cited Causality, you want your animation to be "driven" by something like a slider?

Comment: @Galandil yes - essentially my object moving between max and min is like a slider.

Answer (score 3):

For every state, there is a toggle in the animator to take a `normalizedTime` through a float parameter. As the name suggests, setting its value to 0 will give an animation at 0% and 1 at 100%. You can set the value of the parameter through

```
animator.SetFloat ("AnimStateTime", 0.5f);
```

if you want to smooth the transition, use

```
animator.SetFloat ("AnimStateTime", 0.5f, 1, 10 * Time.deltaTime);
```

[image: NormalizedTime]

Comment: Will this make sure the object does not jump to this float, but "fast forwards" through to it?

Comment: It will jump to that animation duration. If you want a smooth 'jumping', you'll have to do that manually through scripting and send the animator the intermediate values in the update loop

Comment: I forgot, actually there is ` SetFloat(string name, float value, float dampTime, float deltaTime)` which will automatically do the smoothing for you.